# Using Directories in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get some data out of excel files. Never used excel before but I understand VB. So I have a file with a button my boss implemented as well as his code he used. Here is the code:
[image]
[image]

(you can see the "Get Data" button in there)
My exact problem is that I don't know a lot about excel so if someone could help me figure out what is going on as well as figuring out how to correctly use directories that would be awesome! For more context when you click the button it gets all files in the directory and then the user clicks a file then excel follows a macro to get some data out of sed file.

Right now it returns nothing but there is 5 files in that directory?

Here is what the default directory looks like after edit:
[image]
And here is the files in my directory:
[image]

Comment: Please do not include irrelevant tags

Comment: what is in Range("DefaultDirectory")

Comment: one sec will add edit for it

Comment: I cant see the images at work

Comment: okay so row 1 says default directory and right now row2 is just the file path to a folder i have on my desktop that contains all of my excel files

Comment: I would check out the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library for some classes that make folder crawling simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tim Williams says ... Insert the back slash after the folder name

```
DirNow = Dir(Range("DefaultDirectory") + "\WFP*", vbDirectory)
```

**EDIT**

Basic troublseshooting

1. Does it it compile?
   Looks like "UserFormDataa" - should maybe be "UserFormData"
2. Add Debug.Print DirNow after it's set and show us the display
3. If that's not right add line
   Debug.Print Range("DefaultDirectory") to makes sure range is defined properly
4. Remove vbDirectory - unless you're going to handle processing files under the matching sub-folders

Comment: Actually got this to work. I had something wrong on my side. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the terminal backslash on your default directory.

```
C:\Users\CUCCOMTT\Desktop\Excel Project\
```

Otherwise you're looking for files named

```
C:\Users\CUCCOMTT\Desktop\Excel ProjectWFP
```

Comment: I'm sorry were does that go exactly?